# Zoom in webview loading a flash file

Tags: android, flash, webview, zooming

This is the `WebView` I have in my application

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.setLongClickable(false);
webView.setWebViewClient(wvc);
webView.loadUrl("file://" + path);
```

The webview is loading a local flash (.swf) file

I've been trying to get create a zoom system that works in the `WebView`. I've already tried using the `setBuiltInZoomControls(true)`, but when I zoom in, the flash automatically adjusts itself to the `WebView`'s size, making the zoom controls useless.

How can I stop this from happening? (in the flash file or the `WebView`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049343/how-to-control-zoom-in-webview  Did you look at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I used to correct this was not to load directly the flash file, but to load an HTML file with a flash object within it.

The pitch zoom doesn't work (when done on/over the flash), but the built-in zoom control from the `WebView` are correctly working.