# Canvas - zooming in, shifting, and scaling on Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm currently implementing a draw function on a webview image (the elephant below). I don't have a problem drawing on it but the zoom function does some funky stuff (2nd image below) on the drawing. When I zoom in, the drawing doesn't zoom but rather shifts over. Drawing at zoomed also doesn't work. My code is below:

[image: Normal]

[image]

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    canvas.restore();
    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    float touchX = event.getX() / mScaleFactor + clipBounds.left;
    float touchY = event.getY() / mScaleFactor + clipBounds.top;
    if (Deal.on)
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
    }
    else {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public class ScaleGestureListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I managed to get the canvas to redraw with zooming using the GestureDetector's scale factor. Additionally, I have a switch that toggles from drawing to zooming/webview controls. A problem that I run into is that double tap on WebView doesn't trigger the onScale gesture. Which means the canvas doesn't get redrawn and shifts on the zoom in.

I need to implement a feature that detects how much the scale factor is affected by the double tap zoom in. If anyone can suggest a solution to that. Here's the update code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    canvas.save();
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/mScaleFactor);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    float touchX = (event.getX() + clipBounds.left) / mScaleFactor;
    float touchY = (event.getY() + clipBounds.top) / mScaleFactor;
    if (Deal.on){
        if (event.getPointerCount() > 1){
            return false;
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   // Try for a width based on our minimum
   int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
   int w = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1);

   //int minh = MeasureSpec.getSize(w) - (int)mTextWidth + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop();
   int h = resolveSizeAndState(MeasureSpec.getSize(w), heightMeasureSpec, 0);
   setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

public class ScaleGestureListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        if(Deal.on == false) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 20.0f));
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try performing the scale before you do any drawing with the canvas?

Comment: And the question is? Why drawing isn't scaled or why it doesn't work? Obviously, You do the drawing with the same paint every time, so why it should be zoomed?

Comment: Why are you zooming at all on doubleTap, and where is that implemented? You have to change the scaleFactor accordingly if you do.

Comment: How do you change the scale factor accordingly? Is there another implemented method other than onScale that would detect double that change on my Gesture Listener?

Comment: The reason I'm zooming in on double tap is because I'm drawing on  a WebView

Comment: Since you are implementing zoom yourself, I think you should disable the default webview zoom, implement you own onTouchEvent, as you do, but don't call super. Check out this question for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049343/how-to-control-zoom-in-webview

Comment: Hello @ono are you getting any solution to your problem I am also stuck in this same issue.You have any solution can you please share it because it is useful to others.

Comment: @user3711560 I got it to work via ZoomImage view (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970419/capdroids-pinch-to-zoom-method-doesnt-work-blank-screen) I found with some modifications. This is the questions I asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006428/zoomview-canvas-matrix-android/20011005#20011005

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented this behaviour, but in a slightly different way. I used a matrix to handle all the zooming and scrolling (and rotation, in my case). It makes for neat code and works like clockwork. I don't know what is causing your funky behaviour, though.

Store a Matrix and another path as class members:

```
Matrix drawMatrix = new Matrix();
Path transformedPath = new Path();
```

Replace your onScale:

```
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    Matrix transformationMatrix = new Matrix();

    //Zoom focus is where the fingers are centered, 
    transformationMatrix.postTranslate(-detector.getFocusX(), -detector.getFocusY());

    transformationMatrix.postScale(detector.getScaleFactor(), detector.getScaleFactor());

/* Using getFocuShift allows for scrolling with two pointers down. Remove it to skip this functionality */
    transformationMatrix.postTranslate(detector.getFocusX() + detector.getFocusShiftX(), detector.getFocusY() + detector.getFocusShiftY());

    drawMatrix.postConcat(transformationMatrix);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

in onDraw; skip saving the canvas, instead:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, drawMatrix, canvasPaint);
    transformedPath.rewind();
    transformedMatrix.addPath(drawPath);
    transformedPath.transform(drawMatrix, null);
    canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, drawPaint);
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Actually, this won't actually zoom the path. It will draw in the zoomed-in position, but the line width will be the same as originally. That is what I wanted when I did this, but maybe not what you want.

Comment: The line width should scale with the zoom; it should get thicker if its zoomed in.

Comment: Well, it isn't pretty, but you can change the lineWidth according to the zoom to achieve this effect.

Comment: How do you get the zoom is the real question? If you double tap on a WebView it zooms in automatically. Is there a way to get that zoom amount?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to accomplish all the different effects you are trying to do in a very simple manner is making use of the canvas method

> canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint);

This method allow you, to take the whole source bitmap or just a small sample of it (Rect src), and project it as you wish (Rect dst) doing the scaling / translation of matrix calculations automatically for you as shown in the example below:

This example just scales / zooms the whole image...

```
     Canvas canvas = null;
     Bitmap elephantBmp = null;
     Rect src = new Rect();
     Rect postRect = new Rect();
     Paint paintIfAny = new Paint();

     //To scale the whole image, first take the whole source and then postRect with a bigger size... 
     src.top = src.left = 0;
     src.right = elephantBmp.getWidth();
     src.bottom = elephantBmp.getHeight();
     //Here you have the chance to translate / scale the image(in this case i will not translate it but just scale it...)
     postRect.top = postRect.left = 0;
     postRect.right = (int)(elephantBmp.getWidth() * 1.1F);
     postRect.bottom = (int)(elephantBmp.getHeight() * 1.1F);

     canvas.drawBitmap(elephantBmp, src, postRect, paintIfAny);
```

And this example takes just a sample of the image and shows it "inner zoom effect"

```
     Canvas canvas = null;
     Bitmap elephantBmp = null;
     Rect src = new Rect();
     Rect postRect = new Rect();
     Paint paintIfAny = new Paint();

    //To shift the whole image, first take the part of the original source image you want to show 
     src.top = topPosition;//Top coordinate of piece of image to show
     src.left = leftPosition;//Left coordinate of piece of image to show
     src.right = rightPosition;//Right coordinate of piece of image to show
     src.bottom = bottomPosition;//Bottom coordinate of piece of image to show
     //Here you have the chance to show it as big as you want...
     postRect.top = postRect.left = 0;
     postRect.right = (int)(src.width() * 1.1F);
     postRect.bottom = (int)(src.height() * 1.1F);

     canvas.drawBitmap(elephantBmp, src, postRect, paintIfAny);
```

By making use of these src/dst objects you can do pretty much any effect you want on android, is a simple and really powerful tool

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to draw paths only one time, and keep the zooming the responsibility of the canvas itself

```
private boolean pathsDrawn;

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    canvas.save();
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/mScaleFactor);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, 0, 0);

    if(!pathsDrawn) {
       canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
       pathsDrawn = true;
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: This just draws the path when I take the finger off. It doesn't affect zooming

Answer (score 0):

```
check below code will help you.

//CUSTOM IMAGEVIEW
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ScaleImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {

static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 10f;
static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;

float lastTouchX;
float lastTouchY;
final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

private Context mContext;
private float MAX_SCALE = 2f;

private static Matrix mMatrix;
private final float[] mMatrixValues = new float[9];

// display width height.
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;

private int mIntrinsicWidth;
private int mIntrinsicHeight;

private float mScale;
private float mMinScale;

private float mPrevDistance;
private boolean isScaling;

private int mPrevMoveX;
private int mPrevMoveY;
private GestureDetector mDetector;

Paint paint = new Paint();
public static Path path = new Path();

public static int imageheight, imagewidth;

String TAG = "ScaleImageView";

public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
super(context, attr);
this.mContext = context;
initialize();
}

public ScaleImageView(Context context) {
super(context);
this.mContext = context;
initialize();
}

private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
super.setImageBitmap(bm);
this.initialize();
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
super.setImageResource(resId);
this.initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
this.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
this.mMatrix = new Matrix();
Drawable d = getDrawable();

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

if (d != null) {
    mIntrinsicWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    mIntrinsicHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}
mDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext,
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                maxZoomTo((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                cutting();
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
        });

}

@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
mWidth = r - l;
mHeight = b - t;

mMatrix.reset();
int r_norm = r - l;
mScale = (float) r_norm / (float) mIntrinsicWidth;

int paddingHeight = 0;
int paddingWidth = 0;
// scaling vertical
if (mScale * mIntrinsicHeight > mHeight) {
    mScale = (float) mHeight / (float) mIntrinsicHeight;
    mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
    paddingWidth = (r - mWidth) / 2;
    paddingHeight = 0;
    // scaling horizontal
} else {
    mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
    paddingHeight = (b - mHeight) / 2;
    paddingWidth = 0;
}
mMatrix.postTranslate(paddingWidth, paddingHeight);

setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
mMinScale = mScale;
zoomTo(mScale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
cutting();
return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
}

protected float getValue(Matrix matrix, int whichValue) {
matrix.getValues(mMatrixValues);
return mMatrixValues[whichValue];
}

protected float getScale() {
return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X);
}

public float getTranslateX() {
return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_X);
}

protected float getTranslateY() {
return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_Y);
}

protected void maxZoomTo(int x, int y) {
if (mMinScale != getScale() && (getScale() - mMinScale) > 0.1f) {
    // threshold 0.1f
    float scale = mMinScale / getScale();
    zoomTo(scale, x, y);
} else {
    float scale = MAX_SCALE / getScale();
    zoomTo(scale, x, y);
}
}

public void zoomTo(float scale, int x, int y) {
if (getScale() * scale < mMinScale) {
    return;
}
if (scale >= 1 && getScale() * scale > MAX_SCALE) {
    return;
}
mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
// move to center
mMatrix.postTranslate(-(mWidth * scale - mWidth) / 2,
        -(mHeight * scale - mHeight) / 2);

// move x and y distance
mMatrix.postTranslate(-(x - (mWidth / 2)) * scale, 0);
mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(y - (mHeight / 2)) * scale);
setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
}

public void cutting() {
int width = (int) (mIntrinsicWidth * getScale());
int height = (int) (mIntrinsicHeight * getScale());

imagewidth = width;
imageheight = height;

if (getTranslateX() < -(width - mWidth)) {
    mMatrix.postTranslate(-(getTranslateX() + width - mWidth), 0);
}
if (getTranslateX() > 0) {
    mMatrix.postTranslate(-getTranslateX(), 0);
}
if (getTranslateY() < -(height - mHeight)) {
    mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(getTranslateY() + height - mHeight));
}
if (getTranslateY() > 0) {
    mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -getTranslateY());
}
if (width < mWidth) {
    mMatrix.postTranslate((mWidth - width) / 2, 0);
}
if (height < mHeight) {
    mMatrix.postTranslate(0, (mHeight - height) / 2);
}
setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
}

private float distance(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1) {
float x = x0 - x1;
float y = y0 - y1;
return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private float dispDistance() {
return FloatMath.sqrt(mWidth * mWidth + mHeight * mHeight);
}

public void clear() {
path.reset();
invalidate();
}

public static void save() {

Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        ScaleImageViewActivity.imageview.getWidth(),
        ScaleImageViewActivity.imageview.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

Drawable bgDrawable = ScaleImageViewActivity.imageview.getDrawable();

if (bgDrawable != null)
    bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
else
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

ScaleImageViewActivity.imageview.draw(canvas);

ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);

Bitmap FinalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bs.toByteArray(), 0,
        bs.toByteArray().length);

ScaleImageViewActivity.imageview.setImageBitmap(FinalBitmap);
path.reset();

// ScaleImageViewActivity.imageview.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);

}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (!ScaleImageViewActivity.flag) {

    if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
        if (touchCount >= 2) {
            float distance = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                    event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
            mPrevDistance = distance;
            isScaling = true;
        } else {
            mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
            mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
        }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (touchCount >= 2 && isScaling) {
            float dist = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                    event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
            float scale = (dist - mPrevDistance) / dispDistance();
            mPrevDistance = dist;
            scale += 1;
            scale = scale * scale;
            zoomTo(scale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
            cutting();
        } else if (!isScaling) {
            int distanceX = mPrevMoveX - (int) event.getX();
            int distanceY = mPrevMoveY - (int) event.getY();
            mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
            mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
            cutting();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP:
        if (event.getPointerCount() <= 1) {
            isScaling = false;
        }
        break;
    }
} else {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;
        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
        int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
        for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
            float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
            float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
            path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
        }
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
    }

    invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

    lastTouchX = eventX;
    lastTouchY = eventY;
}
return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDraw(canvas);
if (ScaleImageViewActivity.flag)
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

}

//ACTIVITY

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ScaleImageViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btndraw, btnzoom, btnsave;

public static ScaleImageView imageview;
public static boolean flag = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
initwidget();
}

private void initwidget() {

imageview = (ScaleImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_save);
btndraw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_zoom_draw);
btnzoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_zoom_zoom);

btndraw.setOnClickListener(this);
btnzoom.setOnClickListener(this);
btnsave.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (btndraw.equals(arg0)) {
    flag = true;
} else if (btnzoom.equals(arg0)) {
    flag = false;
} else if (btnsave.equals(arg0)) {
    ScaleImageView.save();
}
}
}
main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_zoom_zoom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Zoom" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_zoom_draw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Draw" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.matabii.dev.scaleimageview.ScaleImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/sample" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Android_101:_implementing_a_drawing_canvas). Here the author uses two Matrix objects to manage translations and scalling. I suggest you to use matrices, otherwise calculating new coordinates can be tricky and tedious. Your problem is caused by not managing translations correctly. Note: in the tutorial, inside OnDraw(), it misses the `canvas.concat(matrix)`, put it right after `canvas.drawBitmap(...)`